# FLutter app stop on Nougat 7.0

Tags: android, flutter

I am running my Flutter app on one of my device (Marshmallow 6.0) works fine.
But If I run the same app on another device (Nougat 7.0) it through below error and app does not start.

I google the same but did not get any result.

`E/FlutterMain(20122): Flutter initialization failed.
E/FlutterMain(20122): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.flutter.view.ResourceExtractor.waitForCompletion()' on a null object reference
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterMain.java:196)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at io.flutter.app.FlutterActivityDelegate.onCreate(FlutterActivityDelegate.java:159)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity.onCreate(FlutterActivity.java:86)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at app.ntext.ntextdev.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:10)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6666)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2677)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2789)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1527)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6251)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
E/FlutterMain(20122):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)`

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try running "flutter clean" in the terminal and run it again. Also make sure you have the latest version of Flutter running or upgrade it using "flutter upgrade".